# Unable to connect the native Kafka client to Azure function app (Want to pass the Kafka trigger from native client to function app in Azure)

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions, eventtrigger

We've native Kafka running in a Linux server in Azure (not confluent or event hubs). We are trying to create the Kafka trigger of this native instance on Azure function app.

The Microsoft documentation is mentioning about two types of event providers i.e. Event hubs and Confluent and not talking about the native Kafka client.

Microsoft documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-kafka-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cevent-hubs&pivots=programming-language-csharp

So, is there any way we can connect the native Kafka client (kafka trigger) to Azure function app.

Looking forward for the support and please let me know in case need additional details.

Tried: checked for the samples to connect the Kafka native client which is running in a VM inside Azure to Azure function app and there is no luck.

Documentation is only mentioning about the Kafka hosted in Azure Event Hubs or confluent cloud and no information about the native Kafka clients.

Expectation: Should be able to pass the Kafka trigger from the native client to Azure function app

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `KafkaTrigger("BrokerList",` and give your own Kafka cluster address? The listed examples are only changing the username/password settings, not the cluster itself.

Comment: We've not tried it as the sample not mentioned about passing the Kafka cluster directly. Also, not sure how to pass the Kafka cluster address directly. It would be great if you can share some sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Have you written any Kafka client before? What value do you typically provide for `bootstrap.servers`? Copy the exact same string

Comment: No, I am new to the Kafka. Will try what you suggested and update you. Thanks a lot!!